# How to send a message between Chrome extension popup and content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Following the Google tutorial, I am sending a message from a popup script to a content script. The message passes correctly but when I call the response callback I get the following error:

```
Attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

This is popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  { active: true, currentWindow: true }, 
  function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
      tabs[0].id, 
      { greeting: "hello" }, 
      function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
});
```

This is content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse('goodbye'); // <- Error here
  });
```

How can I send this message and get the response back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be due to an alert on the content page which caused the popup window to close. This in turn breaks the connection between the popup and the content script.

Answer (score -1):

This example demonstrates sending a message to the content script in the selected tab.

```
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

reference [Link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging)